# pandas str contain to return match

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas `str.contains()` where evaluated to `True` in the way below returns the row. But how to return the match instead of the row?

```
In [1]: df 

language           level
java programming   beginner
c/c++              intermediate
php                beginner

In [2]: df[df['language'].str.contains("java|php|python")==True]

language           level
java programming   beginner
php                beginner

In [3]: #but should return match too instead of row:
language           level     matched_skill
java programming   beginner  java
php               beginner   php

In [4]: df[['matched_skill']]

java
php
```

Comment: This is almost certainly unnecessary: `==True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and then remove rows with `NaN` by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df['matched_skill'] = df['language'].str.extract("(java|php|python)", expand=False)
print (df)
           language         level matched_skill
0  java programming      beginner          java
1             c/c++  intermediate           NaN
2               php      beginner           php

df.dropna(subset=['matched_skill'], inplace=True)
print (df)
           language     level matched_skill
0  java programming  beginner          java
2               php  beginner           php
```